# Testing number of successfully returned threads using rspec

Tags: ruby, multithreading, unit-testing, testing, rspec

How can I test that the number of successfully returned threads to the main thread is equal to the number of threads created in rspec?

Answer (score 0):

```
describe '#update_tokens' do
  it 'is threadsafe', db_strategy: :truncation do
    u = create(:user)
    thread_injected = false
    time = Time.now
    allow(Time).to receive(:now) do
      unless thread_injected
        thread_injected = true
        Thread.new { u.reload.update_tokens('c2', 't2') }.join
      end
      time
    end
    u.update_tokens('c1', 't1')
    expect(u.tokens['c1']).not_to be_nil
    expect(u.tokens['c2']).not_to be_nil
  end
end
```

Original: http://blog.paulrugelhiatt.com/rails/rspec/2015/09/28/testing-thread-safety-concurrency-in-rspec.html